# How to import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

Tags: java, hibernate

How to import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional ?

I have @Transactional in red.
Despite it belongs to org.springframework  I can not import it.

https://github.com/anatoliy19/test_CRUD.git

Comment: It's in the `spring-tx` package which is a transitive dependency of `spring-orm`, so it should work.  Check to make sure your IDE is setup correctly, and that you have that package as a dependency.

Comment: Could you clarify the question, please? I've cloned your project from Github and `mvn clean install package` is not successful because your `pom.xml` file is corrupted. I've tried to fix it, but then I see a lot of other problems where proper imports are just missing. After adding all the imports everything works fine and your `@Transactional` annotations are properly recognized everywhere without any changes from my side.

Comment: @AndrejIstomin  So, I should add some imports from where?  Thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've fixed `pom.xml` in your project. You had the file corrupted, I've just removed one of the `build` sections (maybe the wrong one, please check, which one you want to leave). Then I've fixed `AppConfig` class where some imports were missing. Now `mvn clean install package` command works fine for me: that means, that you do not have compilation errors anymore.
I've sent you a [PR](https://github.com/anatoliy19/test_CRUD/pull/1) with my changes.
Please let me know if that solves the problem.

Comment: it works fine. @Transactional is still red.  I tried to write manually 
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional   
though it says:  
java: package org.springframework.dao.annotation does not exist

Comment: @Anatoly if `mvn clean install package` command works without errors, then the problem must be in IDE. Which IDE do you use? If it's IntellijIdea, try to reload the project and.or clean invalidate cache, sometimes it helps.

Comment: Yes, IntellijIdea.  I made invalidate cache, though @Transactional  still red.  
Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Anatoly Try to re-import the project: close Idea, remove `.idea` directory, open Idea and open project by selecting `pom.xml`. BTW, what version on Idea do you use?

Comment: Yes, re-import with removal helped!
IDEA 2022.1.3 Ultimate.